# Can I include custom app helpers in a module's view.yml in Symfony?

Tags: php, view, symfony1, helper

I know I can include the helper in the module's template with `use_helper('foo')` 
but is it possible to include it in the module's view.yml, and if so, what is the syntax?
Thanks

Comment: Turns out helpers should be included in settings.yml, not view.yml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check symfony docs on this matters, seems like the view.yml configuration file on modules, althoug is a valid way to configure your views, its discouraged. Please read this [Symfony view.yml configuration](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/13-View) , and i would suggest to adapt to the symfony way to do things, most of the times they know witch is the best way to do things